# CodeIgniter's local_to_gmt() not returning correct result

Tags: php, codeigniter, timezone

I can't seem to get CodeIgniter's `local_to_gmt()` to give the right result. It's always one hour off.

All my scripts (`MY_Controller::__construct()`) start with:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Brunei');
```

which is GMT+8, so

```
$datetime = '2014-10-31 08:00:00';
echo unix_to_human(local_to_gmt(human_to_unix($datetime)));
```

should display:

```
2014-10-31 00:00 AM
```

but instead, it's:

```
2014-10-31 01:00 AM
```

Putting `date_default_timezone_get()` right after the `date_default_timezone_set()` gives:

```
Asia/Krasnoyarsk
```

which according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), it's GMT+7, but [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Krasnoyarsk), it's GMT+8.

My **config.php**:

```
$config['time_reference'] = 'gmt';
```

**CodeIgniter version**: 2.1.2

**PHP version**: 5.2.17

Also, if it matters, `MY_Model::__construct()` has:

```
$this->db->query("SET time_zone='+0:00'");
```

I'm using HostGator Shared Hosting, whose server time is `CDT`

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Brunei');` but `date_default_timezone_get();` is `Asia/Krasnoyarsk`. Weird!

Comment: yes thats what i was thinking ;)

Comment: Any idea why this is so?

Comment: rather then setting time zones in each controller. you can put `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Brunei');` in `index.php` of CI, it might not solve your problem but a practice.

Comment: Regarding `Asia/Krasnoyarsk`, the offset changed to +7 on Oct 26 2014.  It would appear some folks are manually editing the Wikipedia list, rather than having it reflect the version stated in the header.  Anyway - `Asia/Krasnoyarsk` and `Asia/Brunei` are two completely different zones, with no links between them, so this doesn't quite make sense.  It appears to work [here](http://ideone.com/GfnAFQ), so it must be a CodeIgniter issue.